# Did mother Teresa ask to allow to Christianise Arunachal Pradesh to receive Bharat Ratna?

Tags: 20th-century, political-history, india, christianity, hinduism

Mother Teresa is a popular person, generally known for her humanitarian work. But from my childhood, I repeatedly used to hear that she promoted and converted many Indians to Christianity either forcefully or under the guise of humanitarian work. You can read [1](https://www.opindia.com/2020/09/mother-teresa-forced-conversions-primitive-medical-practices-suffering/), [2](https://kreately.in/mother-teresa-is-she-a-master-of-propaganda-conversion/), [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_Mother_Teresa) as an illustration. It has been [42 years](https://inshorts.com/en/news/mother-teresa-awarded-bharat-ratna-on-this-day-1453714754257) since she received the [Bharat Ratna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bharat_Ratna) award.

> Mother Teresa was awarded India's highest civilian award, the Bharat
> Ratna, on **January 25, 1980**, for her humanitarian work. Born to an
> Albanian family in Macedonia, her original name was Agnes Gonxha
> Bojaxhiu. She left home at the age of 18 and came to India the
> following year. She founded a Roman Catholic religious congregation,
> Missionaries of Charity, in 1950.

It is interesting to know that the award was given to her immediately after the [enthrone of Indira Gandhi](https://jan.ucc.nau.edu/%7Esj6/314HND01.htm), who belongs to the Indian National Congress party. I don't know whether the [Janata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janata_Party) party has any role in giving the award.

> Morarji Desai March 24, 1977 - July 28, 1979
>
> (As leader of the JANATA PARTY, a coalition formed to oppose Indira
> Gandhi during her imposition of the STATE OF EMERGENCY)
> (Differences within the JANATA party lead to the resignation of
> MORARJI)
>
> Charan Singh July 28, 1979 - January 14, 1980
>
> **Indira Gandhi January 14, 1980 - October 31, 1984**
>
> (Wins elections in 1979-80 after factional conflicts make the Janata
> Party unable to stay together)
>
> Rajiv Gandhi October 31, 1984 - December 1, 1989
>
> (Comes to power after the assassination of his mother in 1984)

Very recently I heard that Teresa didn't accept the Bharat Ratna award unconditionally and received the award with a *constraint to allow the spread of Christianity in Arunachal Pradesh*. Is it true?  If yes, did the Congress Government, which was in the power, allow the spread of Christianity in Arunachal Pradesh?

Comment: @MCW It is only the context, question is whether the claim of conditional Bharat Ratna is True or False.

Comment: For down-voter: Please comment on the issue with the question if possible, so that I can edit the question.

Comment: @MCW Please check now and if possible suggest to me any further improvement if needed as I didn't have much experience with this site.

Comment: Does India allow freedom of religion? If so, why that particular condition?

Comment: @Jos Currently, India is allowing, I am not sure about those times and even in the current times, although the freedom of religion is there, the laws for spreading is forbidden in some places.

Comment: Downvoters rarely explain their votes; explanations have, in the past, resulted in bitter personal abuse.

Comment: @MCW oh... hahaha............ sorry...

Comment: Some relevant information might be found in the Wikipedia article [Christianity in Arunachal Pradesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christianity_in_Arunachal_Pradesh).  It mentions *Christian missionary activity is not allowed in Arunachal Pradesh. Arunachal has prohibited bribery or coercion for conversion since 1978, but there is no record of coerced conversions and no one has been brought to trial under the law.*

Comment: @MCW Personal abuse in both directions.  Without a reason for a downvote, a conscientious and sincere OP has no idea how to improve their question.

Comment: There is a huge difference between "no idea how to improve their question" and personal abuse, name calling, swear words and accusations of criminal and/or immoral activity. That is a false equivalence.  There is a reason why most voting is anonymous.  The hazards of public voting are far worse than not knowing how to improve a question.

Comment: @hanugm It seems whatever downvote existed was withdrawn after an edit, so clarity was *probably* the issue.  One aspect of this question that is an issue for this site is 'Very recently ***I heard that***...'. Without a defined source for this information it is very difficult to apply Historical procedures.  *I heard that* is the bane of a good question, and even qualifies [its own answer](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2125/16951) in the meta post *[Why did my question get a downvote](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/618/16951)*

Comment: There is some popular (i.e. purposeful forced secularization propaganda) misunderstanding that states that a humanitarian catholic order can not actively seek converts or even accept those moved to ask for instruction or baptism. This is total ignorant nonsense, and M. Teresa said various times they were a religious order doing their job for Christ and the souls, not a NGO. It is nonsense to help the body and forget the soul when it can be helped. To deny conversion to someone to ask for it is the same as considering them as sub-human soulless animals not worth of salvation.

Comment: @Luiz yes, I've always understood the current issue in India is related to *organized conversion campaigns* ("missionaries") targeting low-caste and rural populations for "easy" converts, not individual people in India independently deciding to convert based on their own disillusionment or journey of faith. So, someone waking up one day and saying, "I've lost faith in Hinduism, I want to be Catholic (or Muslim, or Buddhist, etc.)." isn't the problem. The problem is when organized religions go into very poor areas in order to entice large numbers of people to convert by promising better lives.

Comment: @Robert Columbia Mother Theresa nuns cann't really promise better lives in the $$ sense. But, this I heard from Indian: a sewer guy was called, who necessarily is a low level pariah. Afterwards, M. Teresa insisted he'd get a hose & soap, instead of dismissing him covered in shit as it was usual.  That was so amazing to him that he returned asking how to become christian. In this sense, it is a better life. An Opus Dei guy told me a similar tale about just talking to a gardener as we talk to low level employees in the west...

Comment: Re: "Very recently I heard that Teresa didn't accept the Bharat Ratna award unconditionally and received the award with a constraint to allow the spread of Christianity in Arunachal Pradesh. Is it true?" - If you can provide a notable source for that claim, you could try asking this on Skeptics.SE.